# How do I change the font size of ticks of matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.ColorbarBase?

Tags: matplotlib

I would like to know how to change the font size of ticks of `ColorbarBase` of `matplotlib`. The following lines are a relevant part in my analysis script, in which `ColorbarBase` is used.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import matplotlib as mpl

axcb = fig.add_axes([0.9, 0.135, 0.02, 0.73])

cb = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(axcb, norm=LogNorm(vmin=7e-5, vmax=1), cmap=plt.cm.CMRmap)
cb.set_label("Relative Photon Intensity", labelpad=-1, size=14)
```

I am using `matplotlib` ver 1.4.3 with Python 2.7 on OS X.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can change the tick size using:

```
font_size = 14 # Adjust as appropriate.
cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=font_size)
```

See the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params) for `ax.tick_params` here for more parameters that can be modified.

Answer (score 2):

Ffisegydd's answer works good, but if you are trying to increase the font size but some numbers disappear because of big size, you can do

```
cb = plt.colorbar()
for t in cb.ax.get_yticklabels():
     t.set_fontsize(20)
```